# VS Code: Show errors on left side on line number

Tags: visual-studio-code

right now I see my errors (eslint errors for example) only on the right side, which I find pretty hard to see on smaller screens. Is there any way / setting to highlight the line number on the left side when the line has an error?

**How it is right now (notice the tiny red square on the right side):**

[image]

**What I would like to see:**

[image]

Comment: you already have the colored squiggles, you have a problem count badge, there is a short cut key for next/prev problem/error, you have the colors in the minimap, why also color the line number

Comment: @rioV8 because I cant see the little red squiggle on mine even though its highlighted red on the right. Maybe its there, but I just cant find it. Highlighting the row would help, because the square on the right is not a precise row indicator.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Error Lens](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=usernamehw.errorlens) acheives your goal: making the error visually recognizable on smaller screens.

While it won't display the error *just* on the left side, but actually on the entire row - I'd argue it's actually even better for what you're looking for, because it even colors the minimap on the right :)

Here's how it looks:

[image]